# Set terminal locale to C.UTF8 permanently

Tags: windows, bash, git, shell

When I'm using `locale` in terminal `sh.exe` from Git (which is activated in *PhpStorm IDE*), this appears:

```
$ locale
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_ALL=C
```

And I can't use any characters like `ą`, `ę` etc.

After using `export LC_ALL=C.UTF8`:

```
$ locale
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF8"
LC_ALL=C.UTF8
```

Everything is ok. But, when I'm running console once again, the problem returns.

How to set it permanently?

*[Windows 10 here]*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you intend to set your changes permanently into Git Bash environment, recommend adding it into the `.bashrc` file, which is loaded every time a new console is opened (or) create a new one if it is not present already. Under Git Bash environment it is present under

```
C:\users\<your-userName>\
```

Add the line to the file

```
# Saves a varible in .bashrc to load the setting upon new session
export LC_ALL=C.UTF8
```

and open a new console for it to take effect.

Comment: I can't find this file and I don't have `C:\users\userName\git-home\` directory.

Comment: Can you find any files with a dot extension under `C:\Users\<your user name>`?

Comment: `.bash_history` and `.minttyrc`